# Can I assign multiple passwords to one Windows User Account?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, passwords, user-accounts

I have a normal password that I use.  However, I also have an RFID scanner that i integrated into my computer.  I was wondering if I could add another password to  a user account, so if I HAVE the correct RFID card with me I could log in using it (it acts as a keyboard), but for any other time, or giving an app Administrative access, I would be able to use my current password.

Is this possible with Windows 8.1, either through a tool that Windows provides, or other software?

Comment: You shouldn't be logging in as an administrator so that account should be a different account anyway. I doubt that what you are asking for is possible in the first place. Still, if it was, then doing this would render the RFID completely pointless as there would be a way to easily bypass the added security which it provides. Although, it has been shown many times that RFID isn't as secure as they'd have you believe in the first place it is still more secure if used correctly.

Comment: I find it curious that companies which have invested in the tech like to threaten people who point out how insecure it is. Shouldn't it be us who is suing them for using shoddy protections for our money? http://www.tomshardware.com/news/Mythbuster-RFID-HOPE,6313.html

Comment: @krowe it's not supposed to add additional security, it's just supposed to make it easier for me to log in.  RFID also isn't secure at all, just like my normal password isn't THAT secure.  I'm just curious as to if it can be done.

Comment: I've changed my mind. I think you could achieve this using a Login Credential Provider. I obviously don't have a lot of experience with this but at least it gives you something to search for information on:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb648647(v=vs.85).aspx